# Drawing an arc with negative rectangle c#

Tags: c#, graphics, draw

I'm trying to draw an arc of a circle in C#. The general code to do this is:

```
e.DrawArc(pen, x, y, d, d, startAngle, endAngle - startAngle);
```

Where x and y indicate the upper left corner of the Rectangle and d the width of the Rectangle (also the diameter of the arc).

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes I need to draw an arc whoose rectangle x and y values lie outside the bitmap I'm drawing onto (they may even be negative), and thus the arc is not being drawn at all.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved it using the Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, points[]) method. I calculated multiple points of the circle doing some math and plotted them as a curve. The result is pretty neat (around 20 points I can't tell that it's not an actual circle), and it works no matter where I want to draw the arc.